# Realm - consuming battery in background

Tags: android, realm

I change my Android project to use Realm recently.
But when it runs at some devices, it consumes battery a lot.
My user report an issue, that is, when my application is in the background, the CPU rate will raise up to 100% occasionally and drains battery to zero.
It's not happened in the previous version of my application which didn't include Realm.
But I can't reproduce this problem on my test device or emulator.
So I can't get the method tracing.

Here's the device information:

> Asus PadFone 2 (A68) Android 4.4 with 2G RAM

And the user's device is rooted by this apk:http://root.360.cn/

I've asked the user to monitor the files which Realm created to see if it's updated frequently.
But no, it's not updated after my application is in background.
And the database file grew up correctly, so the data should already been stored.

And here's the codes how I initialize Realm:

```
Realm.init(this);
RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .schemaVersion( REALM_DATABASE_VERSION ) // Must be bumped when the schema changes
                .migration( migration ) // Migration to run instead of throwing an exception
//                .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                .build();

Realm.compactRealm( realmConfiguration );
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
```

Comment: It's probably something not Realm-related.

Comment: The previous version doesn't have this problem. And it does not include Realm, but this version does.

Comment: Is that the only change?

Comment: Realm shouldn't do anything that drains the battery by itself, but battery problems are very hard to debug. You could try to run a profiler and see if some code path is somehow running when the app is backgrounded.

Comment: Agree. Maybe, when you did the migration, you also changed some non-database logic. I've done that myself. It is impossible to perform a migration without changing API's, controllers (even the types) and so on. Maybe you forgot stopping a background task. It happens.

Comment: Yes, I only change to use Realm to store the data which is downloaded from the server. And there's only one user reports this issue. I thought that maybe the one-click-to-root apk changes some default behaviors and then causes the battery draining issue.

Comment: This problem is confirmed as a bug of Firebase library.

Comment: Hello @Kimi. could you please share more details about Firebase bug? faced the same issue after adding firebase and realm =)

Comment: Hi @user5599807, what kind of the details do you want? Maybe you could use the `trace log` to see if it's the same issue. Here's the screenshot that I reported to the Firebase Support. https://i.imgur.com/MgEHBlU.png